# How to set particular Firefox version in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have web app under tests. And I need to test it from Lunix and Windows with firefox 5 only. So, how can I set particular firefox version in New FirefoxDriver() that Firefox 5 runs only, not Firefox 6 or 9?
I don't want to set path to firefox because it's not useful approach when we have several OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one firefox 5 profile and just give the name of that profile below. It will launch the given profile browser.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile(profileName);
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile); 
driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

refer this [link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) to know how to create firefox profile.