# How to tell Firefox to run on particular version in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to run my tests on diff versions of Firefox installed on my machine by mentioning the respective versions, I read this link [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596097/how-to-set-particular-firefox-version-in-selenium-webdriver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596097/how-to-set-particular-firefox-version-in-selenium-webdriver), but i dont want to create profiles manually and pass the same, is their any way on the run time to decide which version to pick??

Answer (score 4):

Try using `FirefoxBinary` class when setting up the WebDriver.

For example: I assume you have FF 15 installed in `C:\testing\ff15\firefox.exe`

Then, before setting up the webDriver do this:

```
 File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\testing\\ff15\\firefox.exe");
 FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
 FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, new FirefoxProfile());
```

I never tried it, but I think it should work

Comment: am just thinking from the end user prospective, user will be providing the input only as version, is their any way to get the path of firefox installed based on the version??

Comment: well, yes and no - yes only in the case if you have clever folder structure on your disk. Eg every version would be in **ffXX** subdirectory where XX is the desired version.

Answer (score 0):

And for those using python use **FirefoxBinary**

Specify path to firefox binary using FirefoxBinary:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary('path goes here'))
```

Hope it helps someone :)